# set value onClick of table cell

Tags: jquery, onclick, tablecell

I have a custom calendar that I created that basically just creates a table cell for each day of the month.

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on a specific day, display a pop-up (which will be loading a seperate page) that displays all events for that selected date.

However I'm unsure how to set the value of the selected date so that I can pass this in to the pop-up page.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="26" height="27s" 
     class="lightBlue dayPopup" style="cursor: pointer;" 
     onMouseOver="javascript:this.className='lightBlueH';
                  document.getElementById('#Request.calID#day#Day(Variables.cellDate)#').style.visibility='visible';"
     onMouseOut="javascript:this.className='lightBlue';
                 document.getElementById('#Request.calID#day#Day(Variables.cellDate)#').style.visibility='hidden';"
     onClick="setDate(#Variables.cellDate#);" id="#Variables.cellDate#">
```

JQuery Code:

```
$("##setDate").click(function(date) {
        var viewDate = date;
    });
```

I then set a variable that passes the URL in to a function that controls the pop-up.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong trying to set the value of the selected date?

Comment: FYI `onMouseOver` or `onMouseOut` or any other event does not require `javascript:` to be prepended before code. so you can remove them. The `javascript:` is good for using in `href` of a link

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilise the power of "this" which in the code below will refer to the cell which was clicked.

```
$("td.yourCalendarCells").click(function() {
            var viewDate =     getDateFromCell(this);   
    }); 


function getDateFromCell(cell){
     return $(cell).attr('id')
}
```

I'm not sure what format your Id property is in or how you are storing viewDate, so you may need to do a little more in getDatefromCell to return a date back, but you should have enough to work this out now.

Answer (score 1):

You mainly want to send the date to the popup page to show event of that date. Its quite easy
You can take the approach used in http://jsfiddle.net/DQ3Bm/

i.e.

use  tag for keeping the dete/time attached to the element but still show only the date portion to user.

```
<table class="event-calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <time datetime="2013-01-01">1</time>
        </td>
        <td>
            <time datetime="2013-01-02">2</time>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then on the `td`'s click you can fetch the date to pass to the popup url

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".event-calendar td").click(function(){
        alert($(this).find("time").attr("datetime"));

    });
});
```

Comment: This may sound completely stupid but I've not yet worked with the HTML5 Time tag and was wondering how you set the attribute as the calendar date?

Comment: Rather than using the <time> tag which I'm unsure of, I've now added the following to the table cell tag:

    `<td class="lightBlue dayPopup **date-cell**" **date="#Day(Variables.cellDate)#/#Month(Variables.cellDate)#/#Year(Variables.cellDate)#"**>`

And my function is:

    `$('.date-cell').click(function()
    {
        alert($(this).find("td").attr("date"));
    });`

But on clicking a date I get an alert with an undefined message! Any ideas at all?